# How to duplicate view but in a different page?

Tags: objective-c

I have a view in my app that dynamically creates certain data. I want to be able to create a new view just like the old one, but on a different "page" of the app. Is this possible, and how would I go about doing this? A good example would be the Home Screen on an iPhone. When the number of apps reaches a certain amount on one page, it moves on to the next page and continues putting apps (or in my case data). I have a button that writes objects onto the screen, and stores them in an array. I want it so that when `[myArray count] > x`, the next object placed will go to another page, but identical to the first one. 
Any help would be appreciated!
~Carpetfizz

Things I've tried (that didn't work):

- Create an `NSObject` class that instantiates the view through `[myView viewDidLoad]`, and is activated in `myView`.
- Create a separate view controller that does the same thing as above

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for `UICollectionView` to me...

Comment: @JRG-Developer Thanks for the suggestion, but the behavior for UICollectionView isn't the same as what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You should try using a horizontal `UIScrollView` (with `pagingEnabled` set to yes) and a `UIPageControl`. Check out [this tutorial](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html). Another option that creates similar functionality in a little more modern fashion is the [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html).

Update: I recommend trying out [SGPagerView](https://github.com/graetzer/SGViewPager). I just tried it out in the simulator and it looked like a fairly simple implementation.

Comment: Thank you. Is it easy to implement this into my current code?

Comment: It should be doable, although "easy" relative depending on your experience level. I updated my answer with an iOS ViewPager control on github that looked pretty handy.